# Asterisk: PJSIP_HEADER and Websocket

Tags: websocket, header, asterisk, pjsip

I need to add custom header when calling the client's webrtc. Used by asterisk 13 + siphtml5.
Dialplan:

```
exten => 198,1,Answer()
same => n,Set(PJSIP_HEADER(add,X-DRP)=71234567890)
same => n,DIAL(PJSIP/${EXTEN})
```

Asterisk log:

```
Connected to Asterisk 13.17.2 currently running on ubuntu-xenial (pid = 8895)
  == WebSocket connection from '192.168.0.44:58096' forcefully closed due to fatal write error
  == WebSocket connection from '192.168.0.44:58595' for protocol 'sip' accepted using version '13'
    -- Added contact 'sip:a9gn89sg@192.168.0.44:58595;transport=ws' to AOR '199' with expiration of 450 seconds
  == Contact 199/sip:a9gn89sg@192.168.0.44:58595;transport=ws has been created
  == Contact 199/sip:3qogi2fo@192.168.0.44:58096;transport=ws has been deleted
    -- Contact 199/sip:a9gn89sg@192.168.0.44:58595;transport=ws is now Unknown.  RTT: 0.000 msec
  == Setting global variable 'SIPDOMAIN' to 'aster13'
  == DTLS ECDH initialized (automatic), faster PFS enabled
    -- Executing [198@default:1] Answer("PJSIP/199-00000008", "") in new stack
       > 0x7f0ea0071960 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 123.135.239.111:58827
[Oct 23 16:02:31] ERROR[8943]: pjproject:0 <?>:            icess0x7f0ea000ce18 ..Error sending STUN request: Network is unreachable
[Oct 23 16:02:31] ERROR[8943]: pjproject:0 <?>:            icess0x7f0ea000ce18 ..Error sending STUN request: Network is unreachable
       > 0x7f0ea0071960 -- Strict RTP learning after ICE completion
       > 0x7f0ea0071960 -- Strict RTP switching to RTP target address 192.168.100.97:58827 as source
    -- Executing [198@default:2] SIPAddHeader("PJSIP/199-00000008", "X-DRP: 79161234567") in new stack
    -- Executing [198@default:3] Set("PJSIP/199-00000008", "PJSIP_HEADER(add,X-DRP)=79161234567") in new stack
    -- Executing [198@default:4] Verbose("PJSIP/199-00000008", "Set(OldContact="199" <sips:199@192.168.100.97:54514;transport=ws;rtcweb-breaker=no;click2call=no>;+g.oma.sip-im;language="en,fr")") in new stack
Set(OldContact=199 <sips:199@192.168.100.97:54514;transport=ws;rtcweb-breaker=no;click2call=no>;+g.oma.sip-im;language=en,fr)
    -- Executing [198@default:5] Dial("PJSIP/199-00000008", "PJSIP/198") in new stack
    -- Called PJSIP/198
    -- PJSIP/199-00000008 requested media update control 26, passing it to PJSIP/198-00000009
  == DTLS ECDH initialized (automatic), faster PFS enabled
    -- PJSIP/198-00000009 is ringing
       > 0x7f0ea0071960 -- Strict RTP learning complete - Locking on source address 192.168.100.97:58827
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
    -- Executing [198@default:7] Hangup("PJSIP/199-00000008", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (default, 198, 7) exited non-zero on 'PJSIP/199-00000008'
    -- Added contact 'sips:199@192.168.100.97:54514;transport=ws;rtcweb-breaker=no' to AOR '199' with expiration of 200 seconds
  == Contact 199/sips:199@192.168.100.97:54514;transport=ws;rtcweb-breaker=no has been created
  == Contact 199/sip:a9gn89sg@192.168.0.44:58595;transport=ws has been deleted
    -- Contact 199/sips:199@192.168.100.97:54514;transport=ws;rtcweb-breaker=no is now Unknown.  RTT: 0.000 msec
```

And I can't find header X-DRP in debug log of my browser:

```
recv=INVITE sips:198@192.168.100.97:54445;transport=ws;rtcweb-breaker=no SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 192.168.100.97:54445;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPja4ca4b5b-62c2-4953-a761-d13d34696007;alias

From: "199"<sip:199@ubuntu-xenial>;tag=a1b0c71d-f89b-4226-a84e-82e7db8b2b21

To: <sips:198@192.168.100.97;rtcweb-breaker=no>

Contact: <sips:asterisk@ubuntu-xenial:5060;transport=ws>

Call-ID: a47911b2-c6d4-4222-961b-f0418a4e00c0

CSeq: 30108 INVITE

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length: 1085

Allow: OPTIONS,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,PUBLISH,INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,UPDATE,PRACK,REGISTER,MESSAGE,REFER

Supported: 100rel,timer,replaces,norefersub

Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uac

Min-SE: 90

Max-Forwards: 70

User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 13.17.2



v=0

o=- 780155122 780155122 IN IP4 192.168.49.32

s=Asterisk

c=IN IP4 192.168.49.32

t=0 0

m=audio 15018 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 0 101

a=connection:new

a=setup:actpass

a=fingerprint:SHA-256 AA:94:9A:8F:24:9A:BD:C2:6B:BA:57:4D:E2:D3:1F:1E:B1:F9:87:B1:96:C7:29:93:B8:75:16:D6:73:9D:1E:3E

a=ice-ufrag:3e3de33532c2fcdc32d71b2f086be032

a=ice-pwd:78e4b4b93a861933107a205a10cac6dd

a=candidate:Hc92a8000 1 UDP 2130706431 fe80::14:68ff:fe3e:8447 15018 typ host

a=candidate:H6893915f 1 UDP 2130706431 fe80::a00:27ff:feeb:a9e 15018 typ host

a=candidate:Ha00020f 1 UDP 2130706431 10.0.2.15 15018 typ host

a=candidate:Hc0a83120 1 UDP 2130706431 192.168.49.32 15018 typ host

a=candidate:Hc92a8000 2 UDP 2130706430 fe80::14:68ff:fe3e:8447 15019 typ host

a=candidate:H6893915f 2 UDP 2130706430 fe80::a00:27ff:feeb:a9e 15019 typ host

a=candidate:Ha00020f 2 UDP 2130706430 10.0.2.15 15019 typ host

a=candidate:Hc0a83120 2 UDP 2130706430 192.168.49.32 15019 typ host

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:101 0-16

a=ptime:20

a=maxptime:150

a=sendrecv

a=rtcp-mux
```

Is PJSIP supports PJSIP_HEADER for WebSocket? Is there any other way to add custom header to INVOTE for webrtc client?

I use asterisk 13, and siphtml5 web client. Also I check wss traffic with wireshark, decrypt it and still can't find X-DRP header.

Comment: [According to an Asterisk developer](http://lists.digium.com/pipermail/asterisk-users/2019-April/293844.html): `SIPAddHeader` & `SIPRemoveHeader` are for the `chan_sip` module. For PJSIP, you should use the `PJSIP_HEADER` dialplan application. That is exactly what you seem to be doing. So I'm not quite sure what the problem here is. Try using an updated version of the libraries and Asterisk and see if this issue gets resolved.

Answer (score -1):

In asterisk set header using:

```
same => n,SIPAddHeader(HEADERNAME: ${SOMEVAR})
```

You need use a more updated library like jsSip in client. In this case you cant get the server header like this:

```
phone.on('newRTCSession', function(e){
   if (e.originator == 'remote') {
       console.log(e.request.headers);
   }
});
```